# how software testing is actually done in software companies? what tools and techniques are used?

Tags: testing

I want to take up software testing job in software company in future so i want information about how its done.

Comment: This is too Broad. And you can just fine millions of resources just by using Google.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624259).

[image: hwtsam]

Answer (score 1):

If it's Java, usually it's done with [Junit](http://www.junit.org/). If it's .NET, then there are more alternatives. Visual Studio has one [built-in testing framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147%28VS.80%29.aspx), and there are several others like [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/). For .NET, there are also some good third party commercial libraries such as [Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools/webaii-framework-features.aspx).

I don't know about tools for other languages.

Comment: This is for Unit testing. Perhaps he may want to know about System testing etc as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to work with black-box or white-box testing ?

I will write you what kind of experiences I already have under belt and maybe this will shed some light. At the beginning of my career I was working as a software tester (black-box one) in banking industry and we were using internal application for bug tracking - what is an essential tool in this particular position. My duties included regression testing, retesting, exploration testing, bugs finding and test cases preparation by means of Excel :)

Later on (also as a Software Tester - black box) I was working with MES product. And there we were using Test Track Pro to track bugs in waterfall, Version 1 to track the tasks and bugs in Scrum methodology, Quality Assurance Director for test cases creation, execution etc. Test Partner for coding automated scripts. 
Apart from the last duties I was responsible for test cases creation, execution and writing automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

[Testing Computer Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471358460) is a good place to start if you really don't have any background in testing.  Alan's link to [How We Test Software at Microsoft](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624259) is a good second book, I would say.  I would strongly recommend picking up some programming skills, as testing is moving strongly towards more automation.  There are manual testing jobs, but they are becoming less common and there are many manual testers already out there with more experience than you.  C# or Java (and object-oriented programming), plus SQL, is a very good start.